# shared_ptr alternative with no dependencies

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

An alternative to `shared_ptr` to minimize compile time. Intrusive. Reference count changes are not thread safe.

(`#include<memory>` pulls in 17k lines of code)

This satisfies my needs, but I'm curious how it could be improved (without adding any dependencies).

It's not particularly good at handling incomplete types (`ref<T>::get` cannot be used on an incomplete type). Is it possible to improve that?

```
// Derive from this to be refcounted.
struct refcount {
  int rc = 0;
  virtual ~refcount() { }
};

void queued_delete(refcount*);

template<class T>
class ref {

public:

  ref() { }

  ref(T* obj) : obj(obj) {
    if(obj) {
      obj->rc++;
    }
  }

  ~ref() {
    if(obj) {
      if(--(obj->rc) == 0) {
        queued_delete(obj);
      }
    }
  }

  ref(const ref& r) {
    if(r.obj) {
      obj = r.obj;
      obj->rc++;
    }
  }

  template<class T2>
  ref(const ref<T2>& r) {
    if(r.get()) {
      obj = r.get();
      obj->rc++;
    }
  }

  ref& operator=(const ref& r) {
    ref(r).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  template<class T2>
  ref& operator=(const ref<T2>& r) {
    ref(r).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>(obj); }
  const T* operator->() const { return static_cast<const T*>(obj); }
  T& operator*() { return *get(); }
  T& operator*() const { return *get(); }

  T* get() const { return static_cast<T*>(obj); }

  unsigned long id() const { return (unsigned long) obj; }

  void swap(ref& p) {
    auto tmp = obj;
    obj = p.obj;
    p.obj = tmp;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const {
    return obj;
  }

  bool operator==(const ref& other) const {
    return obj == other.obj;
  }

  bool operator!=(const ref& other) const {
    return obj != other.obj;
  }

  template<class T2>
  ref<T2> cast() {
    return ref<T2>(dynamic_cast<T2*>(obj));
  }

private:
  refcount *obj = nullptr;
};
```

Optional deletion which can handle deep nesting (can also do this with `shared_ptr` using a custom deleter):

```
// Ensure deeply nested data structures can
// be deleted without running out of stack.
void queued_delete(refcount* p) {

  static bool deleting = false;
  static std::vector<refcount*> stack;

  stack.push_back(p);

  if(!deleting) {
    deleting = true;
    while(stack.size()) {
      auto top = stack.back();
      stack.pop_back();
      delete top;
    }
    deleting = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post a complete header file (no include-guard/`#pragma once`), so it's unclear whether you also omitted a `namespace Taylor {` somewhere in there. But you should definitely use a namespace around a name as common as `ref`.

---

```
  virtual ~refcount() { }
```

Nit: You could use `= default;` instead of `{ }` here, and you might get slightly better codegen on some compilers. (Virtual destructors are never actually "trivial," unfortunately, but getting the compiler to write this quasi-trivial code for you can't hurt.)

---

I notice that `refcount->rc` is `public`, not `private`. Was that a design decision?

It occurs to me that the proper name for what you're calling `refcount` is actually `refcounted`. The **refcount**, physically, is the data member `rc`. A type which derives from your base class is a **refcounted** type.

---

```
ref(T* obj) : obj(obj) {
  if(obj) {
    obj->rc++;
  }
}
```

I would write this as

```
explicit ref(T *obj) : obj_(obj) {
    if (obj_ != nullptr) {
        obj_->rc += 1;
    }
}
```

Notice the whitespace edits, the use of some kind of sigil for data members (to avoid having two different variables named `obj` in scope), my preference for `+= 1` when the increment is a stand-alone statement, the explicit comparison against `nullptr` in place of contextual-conversion-to-`bool`, and the addition of `explicit`. Non-explicit constructors permit implicit conversions, e.g.

```
struct Widget : public refcount { int data = 42; };

void print_data_of(ref<Widget> x) { std::cout << x->data << "\n"; }

int main() {
    Widget *p = new Widget;
    print_data_of(p);
    delete p;  // OOPS! Double delete!
}
```

It would be better (IMO of course) if this code did not compile.

---

```
template<class T2>
ref(const ref<T2>& r) {
  if(r.get()) {
    obj = r.get();
    obj->rc++;
  }
}
```

This is extremely sketchy. Consider:

```
struct Widget : public refcount { int data = 42; };
struct Gadget : public refcount { int x = -1; int data = 42; };
int main() {
    ref<Widget> w = new Widget;  // OK...
    ref<Gadget> v = w;           // ...sketchy...
    std::cout << v->data << "\n";  // OOPS! Prints "-1", not "42"
}
```

This constructor should be either completely removed, or else constrained (using `enable_if`, C++2a `requires`, or some other trickery) so that it participates in overload resolution only when `T2*` would be convertible to `T*`.

One easy way to mostly-fix this would be to simply add an assertion:

```
template<class T2>
ref(const ref<T2>& r) {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<T2*, T*>);
    if (r != nullptr) {
        obj_ = r.get();
        obj_->rc += 1;
    }
}
```

Here we're lying to the library (e.g. `std::is_constructible_v<ref<Widget>, ref<Gadget>>` will still be `true`), but at least we prevent the client programmer from accidentally writing a program like the test case above.

---

Another way to fix the issue would be to rely on pointer-assignment to do the check for us. Instead of `refcount *obj_;`, let's make our data member look like `T *obj_;`. Then we can write

```
template<class T2>
ref(const ref<T2>& r) {
    if (r != nullptr) {
        obj_ = r.obj_;  //HERE
        obj_->rc += 1;
    }
}
```

And then if `T2*` ***isn't*** convertible to `T*`, we'll get an error on the line marked `//HERE`.

Incidentally, this also solves your problem with `ref<T>::get()` and incomplete types.

---

```
T& operator*() { return *get(); }
T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
```

You don't need both versions of the function, since they do exactly the same thing. Just write the `const` version. (Dereferencing a pointer doesn't need to modify the pointer, remember. [Const is a contract.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/))

```
T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>(obj); }
const T* operator->() const { return static_cast<const T*>(obj); }
```

And in this case you've got the two versions doing different things, but that's still wrong, because they *shouldn't* be doing different things! Dereferencing a pointer doesn't need to modify the pointer. What you meant in both cases was simply

```
T* get() const { return static_cast<T*>(obj); }
T* operator->() const { return get(); }
T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
```

---

Your `void swap(ref& p)` should be `noexcept` — just like your move-constructor, which I guess you didn't write. (You should do some move semantics here!)

I recommend implementing your `swap` as a one-liner: `std::swap(obj_, rhs.obj_);`.

A ***member*** `swap` function will not be picked up by any standard library algorithms. If you want your `swap` to be actually used, you'll need to provide an ADL `swap`, like this:

```
friend void swap(ref& a, ref& b) noexcept { a.swap(b); }
```

---

Your `queued_delete` is interesting. It's misnamed, in that its deletions are **stacked** (LIFO), not **queued** (FIFO). I don't know if that makes a difference to performance or anything like that, in practice.

It's also thread-unsafe, which is not clear from your description/documentation. In standard C++, we can write

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> p(new Widget);
    std::thread([q = p]() {
        q = nullptr;
    }).detach();
    p = nullptr;
}
```

and be guaranteed that the writes to the refcount shared by `p` and `q` won't race with each other. Your documentation clearly states that we can't do that with your `ref<Widget>`. But what is ***surprising*** to me is that we also can't do the following!

```
int main() {
    ref<Widget> p(new Widget);
    std::thread([]() {
        ref<Gadget> q(new Gadget);
        q = nullptr;
    }).detach();
    p = nullptr;
}
```

Here, `p.obj->rc` and `q.obj->rc` are completely different objects, so there's no race there; but then they each call into `queued_delete` and try to write to `stack`, and ***those*** writes race with each other. So your `ref` is completely unsafe for use within a multi-threaded environment, even if you never share any objects between threads.

In theory I guess you could "fix" this by replacing the storage class `static` with `thread_local` everywhere it appears; but, [please don't do that.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/11/14/fiber-local-storage/)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent review!

Comment: When I try to change `obj` to be a `T*`, I get errors because I can't `static_cast<refcount*>(obj)` when `T` is an incomplete type. `shared_ptr` doesn't have this issue because of the separately allocated control block. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: "Was that a design decision?" actually, yes, because I'm thinking of having these refcounted objects also managed through a C API so I can use them from Swift. Perhaps a cleaner approach would be to have `retain` and `release` functions on `refcounted`

Comment: Okay, true, if `obj` points to a `T` and `T` is incomplete, then the compiler won't know how to increment or decrement `obj->refcount` (because it won't know where the `refcount` member is located within the `T`). But my suggestion does *change* your pain point from "I can't call `ref<T>::get()` when `T` is incomplete" to "I can't create, copy or destroy `ref<T>` when `T` is incomplete." I think that's at least a slightly better pain to have.

Comment: I managed to make it work with a `T*` by adding to `ref<T>` a pointer to a function which converts the `T*` to `refcounted*`.